# Why is my method not being called?

Tags: uiview, methods, uiviewcontroller

Why is my method not being called?

My UIViewController should be calling a method in my UIView called myMethod.

It only works on the inital UIView viewDidLoad.

After the view is loaded, I can't call the "myMethod" from someOtherMethod. And I don't understand why? XCode recognizes that the method exists and the method is exposed in my header.

MyViewController.h

```
#import “MyView.h”
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
     MyView *mv;
}
```

MyViewContoller.m

```
#import “MyView.h”
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mv = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:mv];

    //THIS WORKS IF CALLED FROM viewDidLoad
    [mv myMethod];
}

- (void) someOtherMethod {

    //THIS DOESN’T WORK IF CALLED LATER
    [mv myMethod];
}
```

MyView.h

```
- (void) myMethod;
```

MyView.m

```
- (void) myMethod {
     NSLog(@"My Method");
}
```

Comment: My only guess would be that `someOtherMethod` is not actually being called.  Everything else looks right.  Try putting a `NSLog(@"someOtherMethod called!");` in there too to see if the method is ever being called.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that too, and I had the NSLog(@"someothermethod called"); and it calls it, but it never actually fires.

Comment: You mean that the NSLog does show up in the logs, or "it never fires" so you never see the NSLog?

Comment: NSLog shows up in the log, but the myMethod is never called

Comment: If myMethod is called from viewDidLoad, then NSLog(@"My Method"); shows up. It's only after the view is loaded that it isn't called.

Comment: Hmmm, then I would do a search within your code to see if `mv` is set anywhere else (probably to `nil`).  There aren't a lot of explanations for this, lol.

Comment: How do I search and see if its nil? Thats the only instance of mv

Comment: Well, you can check to see whether or not it is nil by adding `NSLog("%@", mv);` to `someOtherMethod` and see what it says the value of mv is.

Comment: Ugh it spits out null. But I don't understand why? mv has been init and is exposed to the entire class.